# Create a Vertical Column Chart with D3 using CSV with Similar String Occurrences

Tags: csv, for-loop, d3.js

I am seeking assistance with my script in creating a column chart with similar string occurrences listed in a CSV file.  I am creating this chart using D3.js V3. The script and technique I’m using to capture the length of the items return results, but the number count of the length is not close to the actual count, very short from the expect item count.  Can someone please review my script and see what is causing my length count to be way off from the actual number count. Any help, suggestion, or techniques will be greatly appreciated.

Below is a sample of the CSV file concept and D3 script. Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
d3.csv("../../data/teamData.csv", function(error, csv_data) {
 if (error){
         alert("Data didn't load, Refresh your browser");
     }else{
        for (var i = 0; i < csv_data.length; i++) {
            if(csv_data[i].Team == "Team 1"){
                team1 = csv_data[i].Team;
        }
            if(csv_data[i].Team == "Team 2"){
                team2 = csv_data[i].Team;
        }
    }
}

var teamCount1 = team1.length;
var teamCount2 = team2.length;

console.log(teamCount1);//Not showing correct number count
console.log(teamCount2);//Not showing correct number count

var margin = {top: 2, right: 2, bottom: 60, left: 2},
    w = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;   
    
var barPadding = 1;  

var chartdata = [teamCount1, teamCount2];

var textData = ['Team 1', 'Team 2'];

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(chartdata2.length))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(chartdata)])
    .range([0, h]);

var svg = d3.select(".chartData")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMin")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 650")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("display",'block')
    .append("g").attr("class","stackChart2")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
   
//Create bars
            svg.selectAll("barRect")
               .data(chartdata)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i);
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d);
               })
               .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
               .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d);
               })
               .attr("fill", function(d) {
                    return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
               })
               .on("click", function() {
                    sortBars();
               });

//Create labels
            svg.selectAll("text")
               .data(chartdata)
               .enter()
               .append("text")
               .text(function(d) {
                    return d;
               })
               .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d) - 10;
               })
               .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
               .attr("font-size", "14px")
               .attr("fill", "black");
               
//Text Label  
  var yTextPadding = 20;
  
    svg.selectAll(".bartext2")
    .data(textData)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "bartext2")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .style("font-size", "16px")
    .attr("x", function(d,i) {return xScale(i)+xScale.rangeBand()/2;})
    .attr("y", 460)
    .text(function(d){return d;});
            
            //Define sort order flag
            var sortOrder = false;
            
            //Define sort function
            var sortBars = function() {

                //Flip value of sortOrder
                sortOrder = !sortOrder;

                svg.selectAll("rect")
                   .sort(function(a, b) {
                        if (sortOrder) {
                            return d3.ascending(a, b);
                        } else {
                            return d3.descending(a, b);
                        }
                    })
                   .transition()
                   .delay(function(d, i) {
                       return i * 50;
                   })
                   .duration(1000)
                   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                        return xScale(i);
        });
  }

 });//End of D3 function
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out referencing this stackoverflow post: [D3 Loading in CSV file then using only specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243458/d3-loading-in-csv-file-then-using-only-specific-columns).  I was able to filter out the needed column from my CSV file which was "Team", using d3 map as follow; var col2data = csv_data.map(function(d) { return d.Team });

Then I followed this stackoverflow post to filter my specific reoccurring item from the "Team" column: [d3.js filter from csv file using multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156864/d3-js-filter-from-csv-file-using-multiple-columns). This post made it possible to get the length of the items to build my column chart. All is working as expected.  Below is the edited script. I hope this will help someone in the future encountering this issue.

```
d3.csv("../../data/teamData.csv", function(csv_data) {

//Filter CSV File to Specific Column
    var col2data = csv_data.map(function(d) { return d.Team });
                    console.log(col2data);

//Filter CSV Column for Specific Column Item
    var team1 = csv_data.filter(function(d){ 
                if( d["Team"] == "Team 1"){ 
                    return d;
        } 
    })
    
    var team2 = csv_data.filter(function(d){ 
                if( d["Team"] == "Team 2"){ 
                    return d;
        } 
    })

console.log(team1);

var teamCount1 = team1.length;
var teamCount2 = team2.length;

//console.log(teamCount1);//Not showing correct number count
//console.log(teamCount2);//Not showing correct number count

var margin = {top: 2, right: 2, bottom: 60, left: 2},
    w = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;   
    
var barPadding = 1;  

var chartdata = [teamCount1, teamCount2];

var textData = ['Team 1', 'Team 2'];

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(chartdata.length))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(chartdata)])
    .range([0, h]);

var svg = d3.select(".plot-div")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMin")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 650")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("display",'block')
    .append("g").attr("class","stackChart2")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
   
//Create bars
            svg.selectAll("barRect")
               .data(chartdata)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i);
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d);
               })
               .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
               .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d);
               })
               .attr("fill", function(d) {
                    return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
               })
               .on("click", function() {
                    sortBars();
               });

//Create labels
            svg.selectAll("text")
               .data(chartdata)
               .enter()
               .append("text")
               .text(function(d) {
                    return d;
               })
               .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d) - 10;
               })
               .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
               .attr("font-size", "14px")
               .attr("fill", "black");
               
//Text Label  
  var yTextPadding = 20;
  
    svg.selectAll(".bartext2")
    .data(textData)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "bartext2")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .style("font-size", "16px")
    .attr("x", function(d,i) {return xScale(i)+xScale.rangeBand()/2;})
    .attr("y", 460)
    .text(function(d){return d;});
            
            //Define sort order flag
            var sortOrder = false;
            
            //Define sort function
            var sortBars = function() {

                //Flip value of sortOrder
                sortOrder = !sortOrder;

                svg.selectAll("rect")
                   .sort(function(a, b) {
                        if (sortOrder) {
                            return d3.ascending(a, b);
                        } else {
                            return d3.descending(a, b);
                        }
                    })
                   .transition()
                   .delay(function(d, i) {
                       return i * 50;
                   })
                   .duration(1000)
                   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                        return xScale(i);
        });
  }

});//End of D3 function
```